# List comprehension and seemingly equivalent Python for loop returning slightly different lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Below I try to generate the same list using list comprehension `active_apps_reported` and a Python for loop `active_apps_reported_2`. The list I am generating is derived from a 2D list of applications `active_apps` and a 2D list of applications that have submitted reports `reported_apps`.  My goal is to identify active applications that have submitted a report. The two final lists report the same 4482 unique values; however, `len(active_apps_reported) == 5875` and `len(active_apps_reported_2) == 5880`.  The difference seems minor, but I am confused as to how it is possible given that both lists were generated from the same two 2D lists.

```
active_apps_reported = [app for app in active_apps if any(app[0:2] == 
                        other[0:2] for other in reported_apps)]

active_apps_reported_2 = []
for app in active_apps:
    for other_app in reported_apps:
        if app[0:2] == other_app[0:2]:
            active_apps_reported_2.append(app)
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: So the code that appends duplicates has a *smaller* result?

Comment: can you provide some sample data and your desired output ?

Comment: I'd expect the opposite,  since using any only counts duplicates in active_apps and the nested for's also count duplicates in reported_apps.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo that may have caused confusion. The list generated via the for loop `active_apps_reported_2` was longer than the list generated via list comprehension `active_apps_reported`. Removing the `else` statement and adding a `break` per Laurent H. fixed the issue and resulted in two lists of equal lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion to have same results for both coding methods:

```
active_apps_reported = [app for app in active_apps if any(app[0:2] == 
                        other[0:2] for other in reported_apps)]

active_apps_reported_2 = []
for app in active_apps:
    for other_app in reported_apps:
        if app[0:2] == other_app[0:2]:
            active_apps_reported_2.append(app)
            break
```

However, I really think that your post is not fully coherent: you wrote that `len(active_apps_reported) > len(active_apps_reported_2)`, but I would have expected the opposite.